# Is there any way to automatically execute a VBA macro?

Tags: vba, windows-7

I would like to set up my computer such that once a day it automatically executes a VBA macro I have written in a spreadsheet, or an access database.

So is there any way to call a VBA macro from a batch file, or something like that?

Comment: Can you define "once a day"? Is it a particular time? What do you expect to do by this macro? [Reference](http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/385166-schedule-access-macro-run-automatically.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure. Use Command-line switches, the links provided are for pages about command-line switches. [For Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207), [For Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/command-line-switches-for-excel-HA010158030.aspx)

Here's an example that I have in a .bat file that loads a msaccess file and then runs a stored macro.

`start msaccess "%localFolder%%localFileName%" /x %macroName%`
In this circumstance `%localFolder%%localFileName%` adds up to the full path of the containing mdb/accdb file and `%macroName%` is the name of the macro.

For Excel, simply place whatever you want to run in the `Workbook.Open` Event. Then load it using a command like the following:
`start excel %workbookPath%`

This will create a new instance of Excel, open the workbook and thus trigger the `Workbook.Open` event. If you think you may have the workbook open, you may also want to pass the read only parameter `/r` so the book will re-open without user input.

Once you get your .bat files set up, just schedule them with the windows scheduler.

Personally, unless your script is Access or Excel specific, I'd recommend re-writing your script in .VBS so that it can run without the overhead of Excel or Access and schedule that. :)

Comment: Also, my goal was to make certain automated edits to a spreadsheet and access db once each day - why would .VBS make that easier?

Comment: @AustinR, Because you didn't specify what you wanted to do. In that circumstance you might as well stick with the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the *Data* in a spreadsheet or Access database, you may wish to use VBS and a DAO object:

```
Set Dbe = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.36")
```

The advantage of using DAO for updating data is that it is a much smaller, faster, lighter object than an Excel or Access application. More robust, more stable. Doesn't throw up a message box when it crashes: Doesn't ever require a GUI login user.

The disadvantage of using just DAO (or ADO) is that it is a much smaller, faster, lighter object: it can't do any thing like printing, or VBA (although you can read a cell, do a VBS calculation, then insert the data).

In particular, a DAO/ADO object can't make Excel recalculate a cell value. For that, you need Excel. And it can't use UDF's in Access. For that, you need Access.

(You can use VBS to automate Access/Excel, but that just adds another layer on top of Access/Excel, so it's often not a good idea.)